# MyBatis не выдаёт единичную запись

Tags: mybatis

Для выборки объектов из БД я для MyBatis 3 написал такой mapper:

```
package datamodel.gis.building;
public interface BuildingMapperBatis
{
    // Выборка объектов по диапазону гео-координат
    public List<BuildingDbDto> getByBBox( @Param("lat1") BigDecimal lat1,
                                          @Param("lon1") BigDecimal lon1,
                                          @Param("lat2") BigDecimal lat2,
                                          @Param("lon2") BigDecimal lon2 );

    // Выборка одного объекта по суррогатному ключу
    public BuildingDbDto getById( @Param("id") Long id );
    /// public List<BuildingDbDto> getById( @Param("id") Long id );
}
```

Конфигурация задана в виде XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="datamodel.gis.building.BuildingMapperBatis">
    <resultMap id="BuildingMap" type="Building" >
        <id column="bld_id" property="id" />
        <result column="bld_geo_latitude" property="latitude" />
        <result column="bld_geo_longitude" property="longitude" />
        <result column="bld_addr_settlement_name" property="addrSettlementName" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getByBBox" resultMap="BuildingMap">
        SELECT bld_id, bld_geo_latitude, bld_geo_longitude, bld_addr_settlement_name
        FROM get_buildings_in_bbox( #{lat1}, #{lon1}, #{lat2}, #{lon2} )
    </select>

    <!-- <select id="getById" resultMap="Building"> -->
    <select id="getById" resultType="Building">
        SELECT bld_id, bld_geo_latitude, bld_geo_longitude, bld_addr_settlement_name
        FROM get_buildings_in_bbox( 0,0,90,90)
        WHERE bld_id = #{id}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Вызываю:

```
List<BuildingDbDto> found = sessionFactory.openSession().getMapper( BuildingMapperBatis.class )
    .getByBBox( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 );
BuildingDbDto dto = sessionFactory.openSession().getMapper( BuildingMapperBatis.class )
    .getById( id );
/*///
BuildingDbDto dto = sessionFactory.openSession().getMapper( BuildingMapperBatis.class )
    .getById( id ).get(0);
*/
```

Метод getByBBox работает хорошо.

А метод getById недоволен вызовом ".getById( id );" и генерирует исключение:
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class datamodel.gis.building.BuildingDbDto from class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getById(Unknown Source)

Но если в интерфейсе я назначаю тип результата List (см. закомментированный фрагмент) и беру 0-й элемент списка, то всё работает правильно.
Но поскольку поиск по ключу выдаст в результате только один объект, то ставить костыль в виде списка я не хочу.

Что поправить, чтобы работало правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя ошибка оказалась в том, что я класс BuildingDbDto объявил с доступом "package-protected". Как только я его объявил public, ошибка исчезла. Почему выдача исключения оказалась связана с типом результата, я не понял, но, по крайней мере, проблема решилась.

DTO я объявлял не публичным сознательно, т.к. хотел наружу передавать бизнес-сущность, а не DTO; DTO преобразовывал в бизнес-сущность в сервисном слое, который находится в этом же пакете. Жаль, но этот подход не сработал.

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали вместо resultMap - resultType.
Измените на

```
 <select id="getById" resultMap="BuildingMap">
        SELECT bld_id, bld_geo_latitude, bld_geo_longitude, bld_addr_settlement_name
        FROM get_buildings_in_bbox( 0,0,90,90)
        WHERE bld_id = #{id}
    </select>
```

Comment: Ну, наверное, resultMap="BuildingMap", а не resultMap="Building" — именно таков id у тэга <resultMap> в конфиге маппинга.
Нет, эффект тот же: метод работает, если возвращается List<Building>, и жалуется на "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getById", если возвращается тип Building.

Comment: Очень странно, у меня куча запросов такого вида и они прекрасно работают. Скорее всего проблема в чем то другом. Может это из-за того что вы 2 раза подряд открываете сессию? Попробуйте выполнить только один запрос.

Comment: Попробуйте написать общую фабрику, например - [ссылка](https://paste.ofcode.org/V6XP6HzHnskvsSGzegExhG). И потом делать вызов таким способом 
`try (SqlSession session = ConnectionFactory.getSqlSession()) {
            BuildingMapperBatis mapper = session.getMapper(BuildingMapperBatis.class);
            BuildingDbDto result = mapper.getById(id);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

По идее майбэтису не важно лист объектов или один объект возвращать. Это решается на уровне связывания результатов c требуемым результатом запроса. Выше верно написали

```
 <select id="getById" resultMap="BuildingMap">
```

вернёт один объект с тем же мапингом.